# If $|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ |\sin x − \sin y|,\text{for all} ~~x, y \in\mathbb{R}$ then $\text{Show that} ~f ~~\text{is}~~ 2\pi−\text{periodic}~?$

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, periodic-functions

Problem :

Let : $f : \mathbb{R} ~
\to ~\mathbb{R}~~\text{be such that}~: $

$$\color{orange}{|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ |\sin x − \sin y|,\text{for all} ~~x, y \in\mathbb{R}}$$

$$\color{red}{•~\text{Show that} ~~f ~~\text{is}~~ 2\pi−\text{periodic}~?}$$

$$\color{red}{•\text{Show that} ~f~ \text{is differentiable at }~\frac{\pi}{2}~\text{then compute}~ f'\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)~?}$$

I know that :

function $f$ is $2\pi−$periodic if $∀x\in\mathbb{R}~, f(x + 2\pi) = f(x)$ but how I applied here? Also second question how ? Can some one give me a hints or ideas?

---

**Edit**

Thanks to Fred's for given a good solution but not complete now we need prove that there no $k≤2π$ such satisfy the equation $f(x+k)=f(x)$.

Comment: Put $y=x+2\pi$ for the first question. Put $x=\frac {\pi} 2$, divide the inequality by $x-y$ and let $y \to x$ for the second question.

Comment: Thank you sir @KaviRama but f is periodic if $f(x+2π)=f(x)$ how in inequality ? I don't have the term of function

Comment: I don't think you can prove that there is no such $k$. Constant function would be a counterexample.

Comment: @NoahTang so we can't say f is 2π periodic ?

Answer (score 3):

$|f(x+ 2 \pi)-f(x)|  \le | \sin(x+2 \pi)- \sin x|=0.$  Conclusion ?

$|\frac{f(x)-f( \pi/2)}{x- \pi/2}| \le |\frac{\sin(x)-\sin ( \pi/2)}{x- \pi/2}| $

What is $ \lim_{x \to \pi/2}\frac{\sin(x)-\sin ( \pi/2)}{x- \pi/2}$ ?

Comment: Very nice sir , thanks!